# How do I configure a Dropwizard application with intermediate certificate?

Tags: ssl, dropwizard

The [Dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/) example project has a [single certificate](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-example/example.yml) [without intermediate certificate](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-example/example.keystore) and the [HTTPS configuration](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/configuration.html#https) doesn't mention anything regarding intermediate certs. Is it possible to configure Dropwizard to deliver intermediate certificates?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the intermediate certificate to the key store that you use for your certificate. To do that when you add the private key you should be able to add a chain of the signed public key with the intermediate certificate. The intermediate certificates should not be added by them selves The intermediate certificate should then also be sent to the client.

Comment: Just revisited this and have added the intermediate certificate to my keystore. Dropwizard doesn't pick it up. How does Dropwizard discover the intermediate? Any ideas on how to further debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Dropwizard uses Jetty 9. From the [Jetty 9 documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#loading-keys-and-certificates-via-pkcks12):

> If you have a chain of certificates, because your CA is an
> intermediary, build the PKCS12 file as follows:
>
> ```
> $ cat example.crt intermediate.crt [intermediate2.crt] ... rootCA.crt > cert-chain.txt
> $ openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey example.key -in cert-chain.txt -out example.pkcs12
> ```
>
> The order of certificates must be from server to rootCA, as per
> RFC2246 section 7.4.2.

I would not include the root CA in the chain because it should be already known to the client.

OpenSSL will ask for an export password. Enter something and remember it for the configuration. The documentation includes further steps to convert the PKCS12 keystore to a JKS one, but that’s not required (PKCS12 works fine on Java 8u261).

Then configure the connector in your Dropwizard configuration file with the filename and password you used:

```
server:
    applicationConnectors:
        -   type: h2c
            port: 80
        -   type: h2
            jceProvider: Conscrypt
            port: 443
            keyStorePath: example.pkcs12
            keyStorePassword: foo
```

You can verify your configuration using OpenSSL:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:443
```

The section `Certificate chain` should show entries for your server certificate and the intermediate CAs.